# how to serialize a dictionnary using Composite fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to develop a POST API. I am trying to use a dictionnary to store social links of an actor model socials links should be stored in a variable socials in the Actor model.

socials= {"facebook":"www.facebook.com/" , "instagram":"www.instagram.com/" ,"linkedin":"www.linkedin.com/" }

Here is the actor model

model.py

```
class Actor:
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
  bio = models.TextField()
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now )
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  socials = models.CharField(max_length=1024 , blank=True)

  class Meta:
    app_label = 'actors'
    verbose_name = _('Actor')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Actors')
    ordering = ('name',)   

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

serializer.py

```
class ActorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    added_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='added_by.username')
    socials = serializers.DictField(
        child=serializers.URLField(max_length=200, min_length=None, allow_blank=False)
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class ActorListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Actor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActorSerializer
```

This is my code. But there is something missing in order to do what I want (I got an error).
Could any one suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say without seeing your errors, but if you are trying to return dictionaries via your API, then I would use the `models.JSONField`

```py
class Actor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
  bio = models.TextField()
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now )
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  socials = models.JSONField(null=True)  # You choose if you want to allow null values
```

Then in your serializer

```py
class ActorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    added_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='added_by.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = '__all__'
```

You won't need to override the `socials` field in the serializer as it will automatically be serialized. I'm not sure what you're doing with `added_by` so I can't comment it on that.

You can now use JSON to load and dump from and to dictionaries.

```py
import json

my_dict = {"a": "a"}
json_copy_of_my_dict = json.loads(a)
a_new_dict_from_json = json.dumps(json_copy_of_my_dict)
```

Comment: In fact the error is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'" . However I didn't use the JsonField in the model because I am using the 3.0.11 Django version and it is supported only by the 3.1 version.

Comment: The you can use the django JSONField support from: `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`

Comment: Thank you : I upgraded the django version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

import Jsonfield and try using the jsonfield instead of CharField but i think CharField should also work.Better you tell the error you are facing

Comment: the error is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'"